# Azure Communication Service Video Call recording - startRecordingAsync requires callbackURI

Tags: azure-communication-services

Starting a recording of a video call requires a callbackUri.  What do I use for this callbackUri?  Anything I can find on it is very vague.  If it is a url that I'm supposed to build the api, what does it pass in? What response is it expecting back? How do I handle using localhost for testing?

```
using Azure.Communication.CallingServer;
...
var startRecordingResponse = await callingServerClient
                .InitializeServerCall(serverCallId)
                .StartRecordingAsync(                   
                   new Uri("https://what_the_heck.com"),
                   RecordingContent.AudioVideo,
                   RecordingChannel.Mixed,
                   RecordingFormat.Mp4
                ).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an azure function just to see what was being sent.  When I pointed the callbackUrl to the azure function, the call worked.  It sent some json, but I didn't have to do anything with it.